# DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.5 in .NET 3.5.1 gives warnings

Tags: .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have decided to use `.NET 3.5.1` but when I add the `DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.5` throught the NuGet Package Console with Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml I get a lot of warnings :

> 1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5):
>   warning MSB3258: The primary reference "DocumentFormat.OpenXml,
>   Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an
>   indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly
>   "System.Data.SqlXml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=123" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the
>   version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
>
> 1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5):
>   warning MSB3258: The primary reference "DocumentFormat.OpenXml,
>   Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an
>   indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Security,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123" which has a
>   higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current
>   target framework.
>
> 1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5):
>   warning MSB3268: The primary reference "DocumentFormat.OpenXml,
>   Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an
>   indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Xaml,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123" which could not
>   be resolved in the currently targeted framework.
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5". To resolve this problem, either remove
>   the reference "DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123, processorArchitecture=MSIL" or
>   retarget your application to a framework version which contains
>   "System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
>
> 1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5):
>   warning MSB3258: The primary reference "DocumentFormat.OpenXml,
>   Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an
>   indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "Accessibility,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123" which has a
>   higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current
>   target framework.
>
> 1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5):
>   warning MSB3268: The primary reference "DocumentFormat.OpenXml,
>   Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an
>   indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Numerics,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123" which could not
>   be resolved in the currently targeted framework.
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5". To resolve this problem, either remove
>   the reference "DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123, processorArchitecture=MSIL" or
>   retarget your application to a framework version which contains
>   "System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=123".

It seems like `DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.5` needs or is using `.Net 4`.

Should I worry about these warnings [and stick to `.net 4.5` where I don't get these warnings]?

I want to avoid `.net 4.5` since they need admin rights to be installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) download page, the SDK requires the **Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.0**.

If you want to use the Microsoft .NET Framework version 3.5 SP1, you can use the [Open XML SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) only.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the 2.0 dll and everything compiles fine. Not sure for how long it will be compatible when users start using Office 2013 though.

Answer (score 1):

Add following dll to your project bin folder -
`DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` (version 2)